# When I know gallons and I know total area how to I get total inches

Tags: physics

If I know total gallons of oil spilled is 94,000 gallons and area is 5 miles by 2 miles long how do I find total thic

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't finished writing this question.

Comment: Sorry it was suppose to say thickness in millimeters

Comment: @Nate: choose either this question or [the other](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426000) and I can merge them.  The other question is more complete, but you can always edit this one to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Convert gallons to cubic miles, and then determine the depth needed to achieve a volume of whatever 94000 gallons turns out to be in cubic miles. $$5 miles*2miles*Xmiles=94000 gallons$$

Comment: And convert from miles to millimeters at the end.

Comment: And make sure you know whether those gallons are US wet, US dry, or imperial.